# Message from Service to Activity never arrives in Handler

Tags: android, service, android-activity, handler, message

it seems I missed something important:

Until now I had an activity that starts an own thread. This thread sends messages from time to time using the sendMessage() method of a Handler that is located in same activity. That works fine.

Now I added a service doing some cool stuff in background. This Service itself tries to send some messages using the same way: calling sendMessage() of the Handler that is located in Activity. But these messages arrive only sporadically, many of them get lost.

So it seems there is something different in Messages/Handlers when a Service is involved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you declare a [local broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) in your activity to receive the information of the service, and then, in your receiver you can send the message to the handler.